# PostLogout redirect issue with OpenIdConnect auth flow in AspNetCore app

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, openid-connect

I've been struggling with this for several days, yet I can't understand why the code isn't working the way it should.

I've got a .NetCore 3.1 Web application which uses an OpenIdConnect authentication scheme. When a user is unauthenticated he/she gets redirected to an identity provider server, logs in and gets redirected back to the client application. This part of the flow works perfectly fine.

The problem occurs when a user signs out of the IDP server. Following a successful logout:

1. the server redirects the user to the post-signout endpoint in the client application;
2. but the application's authentication middleware prevents the endpoint from being called and performs another redirect to the appplication's base url. **I don't understand why 2 happens.**

[Click here to take a look at the behaviour in the browser's network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHOYb.png)

The authentication config in the client app:

```
services.AddAuthentication(config =>
                {
                    config.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    config.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, config =>
                {
                    
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config =>
                {
                    config.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
                    config.ClientId = "client.application.com";
                    config.ClientSecret = "Secret";
                    config.SaveTokens = true;
                    config.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    config.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/Home/Logout";
                    config.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    config.Scope.Add("roles");
                    config.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Role, "role", "role");
                });
```

The Configure method in the StartUp.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            HttpContextAccessorHolder.HttpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("ClientAppCorsPolicy");
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSpaAuthentication();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = s =>
                {
                    var jsPath = env.IsDevelopment() ? "/dev/js" : "/dist/js";

                    if (s.Context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString(jsPath)) &&
                        !s.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        s.Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                        s.Context.Response.Body = Stream.Null;
                        s.Context.Response.ContentLength = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
            
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
            
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = GetSpaOutputDir(env);
            });
        }
```

I've debugged the middleware flow and it turns out that when a signout callback is requested, the request never goes past the authentication middleware which terminates the request and adds the redirect to the response.

Is this expected or am I doing anything wrong?

Another thing is that when I add the code snippet below the redirect works as expected and the post-signout endpoint is called correctly. This is yet another confirmation that the unwanted redirect to the base app url is somehow triggered by the authentication middleware.

```
           app.UseRouting();

           app.Map("/Home/Logout", appBuilder =>
           {
               appBuilder.UseRouting();
               
               appBuilder.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
               {
                   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                       name: "Logout",
                       pattern: "Home/Logout");
               });
           });
           
           app.UseCors("ClientAppCorsPolicy");
           app.UseAuthentication();
           app.UseAuthorization();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. I may not have understood well enough the OpenId protocol signout process.
Firstly, I wasn't aware that SignedOutCallbackPath and SignedOutRedirectUri are two different endpoints invoked at different stages of the signout process. The first one is invoked immediately after a user is signed out of the identity provider. The second one is invoked and redirected to after the SignedOutCallbackPath is invoked.
Secondly, in AspNetCore OpenIdConnect extension the SignedOutRedirectUri by default points to the root of the client application. If one wants the application to redirect the user agent to a different location, one needs to configure the SignedOutRedirectUri property explicitly.

So now the OpenIdConnect extension in the Startup.cs looks like this:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", config =>
                {
                    config.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
                    config.ClientId = "client.application.com";
                    config.ClientSecret = "Secret";
                    config.SaveTokens = true;
                    config.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
                    config.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-oidc";
                    config.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    config.Scope.Add("roles");
                    config.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Role, "role", "role");
                    config.SignedOutRedirectUri = "/Home/Logout";
                });
```